# How to show a date in a DatePicker that I get string to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datepicker

I recieve a JSON with a String date with the following format:

> "22/03/2019"

[image: Date]

how can I show it in a `<DatePicker>` ? Do I have to parse it to a Datetime property? or is it not necessary? I'm getting this result:

[image: DatePicker]

I am trying to manipulate the date in the following way...

```
 string fecha;
 DateTime fechaFormateada;

 public string Fecha
        {
            get
            {
                return fecha;
            }
            set
            {
                if (fecha != value)
                {
                    fecha = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Fecha)));
                }
            }
        }

        public DateTime FechaFormateada
        {
            get
            {
                return fechaFormateada;
            }
            set
            {
                if (fechaFormateada != value)
                {
                    fechaFormateada = value;
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(FechaFormateada)));
                }
            }
        }
```

Now this is when I receive the Json object and format it

```
  public  DetalleSolicitudRetiroViewModel(Solicitudes solicitudes)
  {

            ObjetoSolicitudes = solicitudes;

            Fecha = ObjetoSolicitudes.Fecha.Replace("/","-");
            FechaFormateada = Convert.ToDateTime(Fecha);          

   }
```

to finally show it in the following way in my view ....

```
 <DatePicker  
             Margin="9,0"
             Date="{Binding FechaFormateada, StringFormat='{0:dd MMMM yyyy}'} }"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
 </DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `DateTime.Parse`

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(stringValue);
```

or

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(stringValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also remove the `StringFormat` attribute from your view